# BES API for call statistics and data usage

Tags: c#, blackberry

Is there an API provided as a webservice to get call statistics and data usage for a particular user from the BlackBerry Enterprise Server?

Comment: i'm wondering why the C# tag is there?

Comment: i use C# .net dev environment.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Enterprise-Server/is-there-a-API-to-get-call-statistics-from-BES-server/td-p/679827

Comment: What version of BES? BES 5 is the first one which implemented any sort of web services. In BES 4, your only choice is direct database queries or the BESUserAdminClient/service